# how to populate static database tables in django

Tags: django

I am trying to learn Django and so far I have been able to create models and be able to inject data into the database using views and have a small web app working nicely.

I have a small confusion regarding how Django works with tables that will need to be populated outside the application.

For example, I should have a table called Products. Now the products change extremely infrequently and moreover there are some products that the database should already be populated with. For example, my product model could be simple as:

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What is the Django-nic way to pre-populate this table with a set of products already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Products that should already be populated you could use [initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/) to prepopulate

If some external software wants to change the product list, well hmm if you need to do it manually you can create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

...or you could create a view that takes a json as input ant populates the Projects table using [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) or a simple `create()`

...or you can create a [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) that another program can call like `python manage.py import_products my_products.json`

...or make the external application to insert the products into the same database will be ok too.

Comment: Ok, so anything is fine, it seems :)